# Deserialize JSON request body to existing database item with foreign key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jackson

I have an entity called "Group" that has a one-to-one relationship with a different entity called "Server"

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="groups")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @Column(name="group_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer groupId;

    @Column(name="group_name")
    private String groupName;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="server_id", referencedColumnName="discord_id")
    private Server serverId;

... (Code shortened)...
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="servers")
public class Server {
    @Id
    @Column(name="discord_id")
    private long discordId;

... (Code shortened)...
```

Whenever I make a POST request to my group controller to make a new Group where the RequestBody contains the actual Group and a valid foreign key, I keep getting this error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of '...Server' (although
> at least one Creator exists): no long/Long-argument
> constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value
> (984309670376267837)

The controller looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/groups")
public Group generateNewGroup(@RequestBody Group group) {
    group.setGroupId(0);

    Group dbGroup = this.groupService.generateNewGroup(group);

    return dbGroup;
}
```

How I can elegantly deserialize this JSON request body and link it to a Server entity that already exists in the Database through its foreign key?